# Jira Rest Api Delete version not working as expected

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using the Jira (version 5) Rest API to Delete a version and like the documentation tell me, I pass the moveFixIssuesTo and moveAffectedIssuesTo to transfer issue from the deleted version to a other version. This just doesn't work. The issues that has AffectedVersion / FixVersion set to the deleted version have no version after the delete.

/rest/api/2/version/{id}?moveFixIssuesTo&moveAffectedIssuesTo

Here an example of the call :

http:// /rest/api/2/version/16238?16237&16237

My {id} is an existing versionId I want to delete.

moveFixIssuesTo and moveAffectedIssuesTo are versionId of the version I want the issues to be transfer.

If I do the same kind of action from the Web UI of Jira ( Deleting a version and setting in the form the version to transfer the AffectedVersion and FixVersion, It work correctly and I see the new version in the field of the issues.

Any idea why this does not work as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you changed implementation of service operation - you must use another url for this operaton. For this thing you can change value of attribute *version* in *rest* tag in the file *atlassian-plugin.xml*:

```
<rest name="My Rest Resource" key="custom-rest-resource" path="/my-custom-resource" version="1.0"/>
```